# SFMC/Exact Target Fuel SOAP API - is there a way to create email send definition to custom folder instead of user initiated folder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel-sdk

Now all created email send definition is stored in User-Initiated Emails folder. I want to store it in my custom folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is a way, providing your custom folder is in the User Intiated Sends folder.

One of the properties you can provide when issuing a CreateRequest on the [EmailSendDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/emailsenddefinition.htm) object is the "CategoryID". This refers to the "Folder" and these IDs can be retrieved by using the [DataFolder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/datafolder.htm) object or, typically, by hovering over the folder in the UI you'll see the CategoryID shown in the URL in the status bar of your browser.

[image]